# Why will electrons move from hole to hole in the p type at forward bias, but not from hole to n type at reverse bias?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

This question is about a diode with a p type and an n type. At the forward bias the electrons from the n type to the p type and from hole to hole in the p type. My questions are these:

1. At the forward bias, why does electrons go from the n type to holes in the p type?
2. At the forward bias, why does electrons go from hole to hole?
3. At the reverse bias, why can not electrons go from to holes in the p type over to the n type? I just can't understand this since it was no problem to remove electrons from holes in situation (2)?

Comment: no, they don't move "from hole to hole". A hole and an electron recombine.

Comment: Ah, there are three confusing statements. I suggest to focus at (2) which @Marcus Müller disagrees. (a) Let us say, an electron is at position x, and now moves left to position y, and combines with the hole at y. (b) Now an outsider would see the hole originally at position y has "moved" to position x. (c) I know it seems nonsense to say that a hole, which is an "empty space", like a bubble in water, can move. But we do see the bubble in water moves, don't we? To conclude, I think a hole, like a water bubble, "seems moving". Sorry confusing everybody, just talking to myself. Cheers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Doesn't an electron recombine with a hole, then recombine with another hole, then another hole etc.?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. In this  visualisualisation from 3:14 it is said and shown that the electrons jump from hole to hole: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ukDKVHnac4